# How to link multiple web pages?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

hi all please help me out with problem..
I'm a beginner for web developing and I have doubt regarding navigation bar. I have created a simple web page with navigation bar. I want to link my other web pages to the home.php page using the navigation bar. when the navigation menus are clicked the relevant web pages should display in the content area of the home.php web page. How should I do this? please guide me....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is lacking a code example. Please read [ask].

Comment: You could use an iframe, but note that having all your content under a single page isn't good for SEO (in other words, there' less chance of people finding the site from Google)

Comment: you could use ajax to load each separate bit of content, but as noted above it's not very good for your search results, nor for users being able to navigate directly to a particular page.

Comment: Honestly; you couldn't have done / figured this out for yourself? This is super basic PHP/HTML 101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Sarim answer, you will need to create one HTML page with an empty content area , **"a template"** and then you fill this empty area with your pages. (to avoid repeating the same HTML in all of your pages) , remember *never repeat your self* at any level of programming stack

for example, a template could be something like this

**template.php**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- your navigator and other static content-->
<?=$pageContent?>
</body>
</html>
```

And then build your pages and fill the empty content of your template

**home.php**

```
<?php
 // make the page contents any way you want , like:
 $pageContent = "<div>this is the home page content</div>"
 //then include your template
 include('template.php');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use php include() to have the nav on every page like this

```
// head
<body>
<?php include('nav.php'); ?>
// home.php
</body>
```

Or just an [iframe?](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Comment: i forgot the <?php ?> signs :(

Comment: previously I used iframe, but came out with issues. But this php coding part goes well. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Its batter to create different web pages and link them using anchor tag in your navigation bar.
Like this if home and other pages are in same directory.
`<a href="services.php">Services</a>`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it usin html tag a

example:

```
<a href="home.php"></a>
```

If home.php is in same folder where you created menu bar in html or php file.

[File path](https://www.w3schools.com/hTml/html_filepaths.asp)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to accomplish this. The easiest is probably using includes. First, define the navigation bar file:

```
<!-- navigation.php -->
<header>
  <a href="page1.php">Page 1</a>
  <a href="page2.php">Page 2</a>
</header>
```

Then define each page, including the navigation bar file:

```
<!-- page1.php -->
<html>
  <body>
    <?php include('navigation.php'); ?>
    <main>
      Page 1 contents here...
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

The same logic goes on page 2, and so on. Each time a navigation link is clicked, the new page is loaded with the navigation bar on top of it.